# How to access a vue page from a link sent by email

Tags: vue.js

I have an application in vue configured with vue router, and I have a component with a view to recover the password (recover-password), my problem is that when sending to a user the link of this component for example (https://example.com/recover-password) by mail, it always redirects me to my login page, and not to the recover password page. I don't know what I need to configure in my vue router so that I can access to the password recovery page from a external link or page. Thanks!!!

Comment: You must have a router-guard preventing access, could you post any relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you add `meta: {requiresGuest: true }`  to your **recover-passowrd** inside your router config.
Also make sure that any router-guard isn't preventing the redirect